# accessibility of other controller in my jsp in angularjs

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, jsp

I have the following files

**A.jsp**

**B.jsp**

I have controller and service for **A.jsp** .

I have included **A.jsp** in **B.jsp**. with

```
<jsp:include page="A.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

The Acontroller.js and Aservice.js is not accesable from **B.jsp** and directives included in the A.jsp also not available in **B.jsp**.

How can I use that Acontroller and direcives in the **A.jsp** into the **B.jsp**

I have abserved `<a href="javascript: void(0);" class="ng-binding"` in the inspect elments.

Comment: Have a look: https://www.javatpoint.com/MVC-in-jsp

Answer (score 0):

how your are defined your directive/services? if you define with in the controller then it will be this/scope(same controller can able to access).

create directive/service folder and define your directives into it and define that directive/service into your app.config file then it will accessible to all the controllers.